# VS Express MVC3 newbie redirect issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

I'm brand new to MVC (having done classic ASP for many years). I'm not sure I know how to ask this question. Basically, I want the actions of one controller to seamlessly transfer/redirect to another view/controller. I have tried

```
    public class SetupController : Controller
    {
        ...
        public ActionResult Bicycles()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Bicycles");
        }
    }
```

but the problem is that this takes me to localhost/Bicycles (which doesn't exist). What I want is to go to localhost/Setup/Bicycles. I tried this (adding "Setup" parent folder to controller name):

```
    public class SetupController : Controller
    {
        ...
        public ActionResult Bicycles()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Setup/Bicycles");
        }
    }
```

but this created an infinite redirect loop, which the browser rightly refused to do.

Hope it makes sense what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Your first example works as intended. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
    public ActionResult Bicycles()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Bicycles", "Setup");
    }
```

The first parameter is the Action, the second the Controller.

Since you already are in SetupController in Bicycles action, you would get an infinite redirect. However, from what you mentioned, that is where you are attempting to redirected to.

Comment: this caused infinite redirect loop

Comment: Correct, that's because the method is just redirecting to itself. But that seemed to be what your question mentioned was the desired redirection. Which is your actual expected behavior? That will help us give you a hand.

Comment: I'm trying to group related views under a Setup folder so that they don't complicate the site root directory structure. So, I want, like Setup/Bicycles, Setup/Tags, Setup/Routes, etc. I don't want them directly under the Views root in other words.

Comment: btw, stuff works when I stick to a 1-level-deep View directory structure. But subfolders seem to mess everything up.

Comment: Well, the easiest way is to keep the standard MVC structure, having a folder for the controller, and the views inside it matching action names.
In your particular case, Setup is the controller, and each of those types are actions and views. So you'd have a /Views/Setup/ folder, with a view called Bicycles, another named Tags, etc.
That way the global route will automatically work in your favor and you won't have to route everything manually.
Now, shouldn't the structure maybe the opposite? such as thinking of Bicycles as a resource, for ex, and having a Bicycles controller and a Setup Action.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I'm getting confused, and am going to leave this alone for now. I started out trying to have /Views/Setup/Bicycles, /Views/Setup/Tags, /Views/Setup/Locations, but the "Setup" folder was messing things up. I was getting these infinite redirects and redirects back to the same action. The navigation works if I take out the Setup folder (/Views/Bicycles, /Views/Locations, etc), but I'm left with a directory structure I'm not crazy about.

Comment: I see. Well, I think the problem is you are not entirely familiar with how MVC projects' structures are. Maybe looking at http://davidferguson.me.uk/Blogs/Post/mvc-3-project-structure would help.
The views folder is not "just a folder to organize stuff". It reflects the structure of Controllers.
It is much easier to first accept the standard organization and get your head around MVC itself, and later attempt at customizing structure and routing.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName
)
```

So your first example redirects to Index action in Bicycles controller, hence the localhost/Bicycles.

Comment: how do I go to localhost/setup/bicycles? I want to group related "setup" views under a setup folder. I don't want "bicycles" under the root

Comment: Go from where? As Pablo wrote you use `return RedirectToAction("Bicycles", "Setup");` to go to localhost/setup/bicycles, but you can't put it in the same action as you get an infinite redirect. Put it in any other action ex. Index.

Comment: I'm really just trying to organize views so that I don't have a large Views directory--so that stuff that goes together is physically grouped together. Maybe I don't need ActionLinks after all--I don't know. I can get things to work if I stick to 1-level-deep directory structure under Views, but I would like to think you can nest views in folders arbitrarily and navigate among them easily.